# How to filter a Data Frame records by its size (in Bytes)

Tags: python, pyspark, aws-glue

I have a Data Frame, in PySpark, and need to filter the records of it based on its size (in Bytes).

We are applying this logic but it doesn't seem to work in all cases.

```
purge_timestamp = getPurgeTimestamp()
updatedFrame = df.withColumn('ttlExpDate', lit(purge_timestamp).cast("long"))
```

...

```
columns = updatedFrame.columns
dfFinal = updatedFrame.withColumn('size', getSize(to_json(struct([updatedFrame[x] for x in columns]))))
dfFinal = dfFinal.withColumn('s3Key', lit(""))
```

...

```
dfFinal = updatedFrame.withColumn('size', getSize(to_json(struct([updatedFrame[x] for x in columns]))))
```

...

```
@udf(returnType=IntegerType())
def getSize(value):
value = json.dumps(value)
return len(value.encode('utf-8', 'ignore'))//1024
```

I do not have logs to show since we are processing millions of records and could not print the outcome of each step.

Appreciate the help :)

Thanks!

Comment: What cases doesn't it work for? Do you have an example of failures?

Comment: Also, you don't need a udf to find the length of a json object. Convert it to StringType() and use `pyspark.sql.fucntions.length` transformation

Comment: Hi, thanks! We have used that approached and it worked :)

Comment: @FranciscoPereira what was the final solution?do you mind sharing? im also encountering the same